# Colon in pronunciation guide of 정리하다 [정ː니하다]

Tags: pronunciation

I've just noticed that there is a colon in the pronunciation guide of the word 정리하다 as below.

> **정리하다**  [정ː니하다]

What is the purpose of this colon? Does this mean we should make a pause when reading the word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ː symbol is the [phonetic length mark](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_(phonetics)) indicating that the vowel in proceeding syllable is elongated.

For example listen to the difference between [눈 (eye)](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/m/eng/searchResultView?wordMatchFlag=N&currentPage=1&mainSearchWord=%EB%88%88&sort=&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=72704&font_size=12&nationCode=6&nation=eng&viewType=A) and [눈ː (snow](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/m/eng/searchResultView?wordMatchFlag=N&currentPage=1&mainSearchWord=%EB%88%88&sort=&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=20198&font_size=12&nationCode=6&nation=eng&viewType=A)). Notice how the 우 sound is longer in snow. This difference in length theoretically changes the meaning, but most speakers nowadays will say they actually pronounce these two the same.